# Автонаименование категории при добавлении товара. Django

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Основной вопрос это как организовать создание товара через админ панель с автонаименованием? Думаю по коду будет понятно.

В файле models.py я определяю отдельный класс для каждой категории, из-за специфических характеристик:

```
class BaseProductInfo(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=24, verbose_name='Название')
   manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=24, verbose_name='Производитель')
   photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos/", verbose_name='Фото')
   description = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name='Описание')
   included = models.CharField(max_length=24, verbose_name='Комплектация')
   created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Создано')
   updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Обновлено')
   is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='Опубликовано')
   category = models.ForeignKey('ProductCategory', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
   price = models.CharField(max_length=24, verbose_name='Цена')

   def __str__(self):
       return self.title


class Motherboard(BaseProductInfo, models.Model):
    form_factor = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    chipset = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    ddr_version = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    m2_slots = models.CharField(max_length=24)


class Videocard(BaseProductInfo, models.Model):
    memory = models.CharField(max_length=24, verbose_name='Объём памяти')
    ddr_version = models.CharField(max_length=24, verbose_name='Тип памяти')
    bitness = models.CharField(max_length=24, verbose_name='Битность шины')
    frequency = models.CharField(max_length=24, verbose_name='Частота GPU')


class ProductCategory(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.name
```

Хочу чтобы админ регистрируя товар, не выбирал категорию. Например, занося в админ панели товар 'Videocard' выбиралась указанная категория из бд.

Вторичный вопрос - правильно ли я подхожу к реализации?

Comment: Если вы хотите чтобы при создании товара в админ панели отображалось уникальное наименование товара , вы можете в методе str добавлять к примеру self.pk , возможно я не так понял подскажите , что имеете в виду под автонаименованием?

Comment: @Whatis, я дал комментарии ниже к ответу. Я не до конца понимаю как организовать модели для товаров с уникальными характеристиками, относящиеся к разным категориям. Задача с автонаименованием пока отошла на задний план.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не до конца понял вопрос, но если вы хотите автоматически проставлять категорию, исхрдя из названия товара, то можно это сделать примерно так:

```py
# service.py
def save_product(product_data):
    keywords = {
        'motherboard': Motherboard,
        'videocard': Videocard,
        '': BaseProductInfo,
    }
    for word in keywords:
        if word in product_data.title:
            ProductModel = keywords[word]
            break

    product = ProductModel(**product_data)
    product.save()

# models.py
class BaseProductInfo(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=24, verbose_name='Название')


class Motherboard(BaseProductInfo):
   chipset = models.CharField(max_length=24)


class Videocard(Videocard):
   memory = models.CharField(max_length=24, verbose_name='Объём памяти')
```

Также, если я не ошибаюсь, вам не нужно ставить `models.Model` у подмоделей, тк класс `BaseProductInfo` уже наследуется от неё.

P.S. Интересный вопрос, оказалось, что я не совсем правильно знал, как наследуются модели в django.
[Ссылка для чтения](https://django.fun/docs/django/ru/3.1/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance)

P.P.S. Возможно, я где-то ошибся в синтаксисе/вызове методов, но, думаю, разберётесь, здесь идея, как можно это реализовать, а не конечная реализация.

**UPDATE**

Возможно, более правильным будет сделать такую архитектуру хранения характеристик:

```py
class ProductParameterType(Model):
    class ValueType:
        types = {
            0: 'string',
            2: 'integer',
        }
    name = CharField
    value_type = IntegerField(choices=ValueType.types)

class ProductType(Model):
    name = CharField
    parameters = ManyToMany(ProductParameterType)

class Product(Model):
    name = CharField
    product_type = ForeignKey(ProductType)

class ProductParameter(Model):
    product_type = ForeignKey(ProductType)
    product = ForeignKey(Product)
    value = CharField
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь, но я не уверен в правильности своей реализации, а конкретно отводя отдельный класс под каждую категорию.
Было бы проще сделать одну модель Product и просто через ForeignKey привязать её к модели с категориями, но тогда поля характеристик у каждого товара будут одинаковые, что недопустимо в моём случае.

Comment: @betepok обновил